# htaccess redirect to other domain except for specific request

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We're stuck on a problem regarding .htaccess. We need the website to redirect to another domain, except if the user wants the /intranet uri. Then it should just go on to index.php.

We tried the following but it's redirecting both:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /intranet
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
RewriteRule .* http://google.be
```

We also tried this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/intranet
RewriteRule .* http://google.be
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

But without results. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is use of `REQUEST_URI` variable that changes it's value to `index.php` in last rule. You need to use `THE_REQUEST` variable that doesn't get updated.

Use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/intranet [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://google.be [L,R]

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.